# HTML5 and Javascript game not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

Im attempting to make an idle game in HTML5, javascript, and css. So far I thought I had it going fine, but then when I tested it, it didnt work the way I'd hoped it to. Instead of have one resource go up 1 at a time, it waits a second, as it should, then jumps straight to 101...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='Main'>
    <script>
    var ResourceManager = {
      Re1: {
        Food: {
          unlocked: true,
          quantity: 100,
          max_quantity: 100,
          re_ps: 1,
          workers: 1
        },
        Wood: {
          unlocked: true,
          quantity: 0,
          max_quantity: 10,
          re_ps: 0,
          workers: 0
        },
        Stone: {
          unlocked: false,
          quantity: 0,
          max_quantity: 10,
          re_ps: 0,
          workers: 0
        }
      }
    }
    var RE1 = ResourceManager.Re1;

    var Food_ps = RE1.Food.re_ps * RE1.Food.workers;

    setInterval(function() {
      if(RE1.Food.quantity <= RE1.Food.max_quantity) {
        RE1.Food.quantity += Food_ps;
      }
      document.getElementById('RE1-Food').innerHTML = RE1.Food.quantity;
    }, 1000);


    </script>
    <div class='Main-ResourceShow'>
      <p id='MRS_Re1-Food'>Food: <span id='RE1-Food'></span> - <span id='MaxRE1-Food'></p>
      <p id='MRS_Re1-Wood'>Wood: <span id='RE1-Wood'></span> - <span id='MaxRE1-Wood'></span></p>
      <p id='MRS-Re1-Stone'>Stone: <span id='RE1-Stone'></span> - <span id='MaxRE1-Stone'></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've initialized `quantity` to `100`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `RE1.Food.quantity` to start at `0` instead of `100`?

e.g.

```
   Food: {
      unlocked: true,
      quantity: 0,
      max_quantity: 100,
      re_ps: 1,
      workers: 1
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

`quantity` needs to start at `0`

```
var ResourceManager = {
  Re1: {
    Food: {
      unlocked: true,
      quantity: 0,
      max_quantity: 100,
      re_ps: 1,
      workers: 1
    },
    Wood: {
      unlocked: true,
      quantity: 0,
      max_quantity: 10,
      re_ps: 0,
      workers: 0
    },
    Stone: {
      unlocked: false,
      quantity: 0,
      max_quantity: 10,
      re_ps: 0,
      workers: 0
    }
  }
}
```